# Intellij IDEA appends and unerscore to the "expecpted" type name, why?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, type-inference

This happens to me *a lot* so maybe something is wrong with my settings or something but perhaps there is another explanation ?
Problem is : what is the `Gen[A_]` type? specially what is the `A_` (notice the extra underscore) ?

[image: problem]

Comment: I believe that is to say that it is another `A`, not the same one in Scope.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez what *another `A`* ? there is no other :D care to elaborate ?

Comment: Each `forAll` defines its own **A**. They are different.

Answer (score 1):

The `forAll` used is different from the defined, as you see, the type of the defined is `A`, so if they reuse `A` as the type parameter of the `forAll` used could derive to a ambiguity to the developer, they added an underscore to make them different.